# What's wrong with my array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to build a simple cache script. It's working, however I want to include information if the data was cached in my **existing** JSON.

I tried this:

```
$cached = file_get_contents("./cache/" . escapeFileName($request));
$update = json_decode(json_encode($cached), true);
$update['server']['cached'] = true;
return json_encode($update);
```

where the data of the file *is* valid JSON. I just want to add a `server` node which includes the information `cached`. The script fires a warning and a fatal error:

> PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'server'

and

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use string offset as an array

Comment: why are you encoding and decoding same time? and try to `print_r($update);` and see what you have !

Comment: First encode because the output of the file is a string, then decode to get it to an array and re-encode to serve it as json

Comment: I understand what you where pointing at :D My fail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can first print the array then you will find that the data which it print that is a form of object rather than array. you just add the

```
$update = (array) json_decode(json_encode($cached), true);
```

type cast the data. It will solve your issue.

Comment: you dont have any issue you were encoding and decoding at the same time . so the next time when you were decoding it was converted to object rather than array :)